# Java Program not displaying everything needed in dialog box

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class p1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

    Employee[] employee=new Employee[100];
    double avg;
    double sum= 0.0;
    int count;
    String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of records: ");
    count= Integer.parseInt(c);
    String name,ssn;
    double salary;

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        keyboard.nextLine();
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter name of Employee: ");
        ssn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Employee's SSN: ");
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Emplyee's Salary: ");
        salary= Double.parseDouble(s);
        employee[i]=new Employee(name,ssn,salary);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        sum=sum+employee[i].getSalary();// TODO code application logic here
    }

    avg=sum/count;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        if(employee[i].getSalary()<avg){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Below average");
            employee[i].writeOutput();
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Above average");
            employee[i].writeOutput();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}

class Person
{
    String name;
    Person()
    {
        name = "No name yet";
    }
    public Person(String initialName)
    {
        name = initialName;
    }
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void writeOutput()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: " + name);
    }
    public boolean hasSameName(Person otherPerson)
    {
        return this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherPerson.name);
    }
}

class Employee extends Person{
String SSN;
double salary;

Employee(){
    super();
    SSN="";
    salary=0.0;
}

public Employee(String nam,String sn,double sal){
    super(nam);
    setSSN(sn);
    salary=sal;
}
public void setSSN(String sn){
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<sn.length();i++){
        if(sn.charAt(i)!=' '&&sn.charAt(i)!='-')
            count++;
    }
    try{
        if(count!=9){
            throw new SSNLengthException();
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<sn.length();i++){
                if((sn.charAt(i)>'9' || sn.charAt(i)<'0')){
                    if(sn.charAt(i) !=' ' && sn.charAt(i)!='-')
                    throw new SSNCharacterException();
                }
            }
            SSN = sn;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
    SSN=sn;
}
public void setSalary(double sal){
    salary=sal;
}

public String getSSN(){
    return SSN;
}
public double getSalary(){
    return salary;
}
public void writeOutput(){
    super.writeOutput();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SSN: " + SSN);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salary: " + salary);
}
}

 class SSNLengthException extends Exception{
     public SSNLengthException(){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not valid length");
    }
     public SSNLengthException(String ms){
         super(ms);
    }
}

class SSNCharacterException extends Exception{
    public SSNCharacterException(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not digit");
    }
    public SSNCharacterException(String ms){
        super(ms);
    } 
}
```

So When i run my program only "Enter the number of records: " would show in dialog box and after you input something and enter. nothing else pops up, but there is suppose to be a chain of dialog boxes asking for SSN and Salary and Name then it outputs whatever input if they are above or below average salary. I cant figure out why it doesnt output the other dialog boxes. No errors are shown when running. Also i apologize for formatting the program looks fine in Netbeans but when i copied over i had to indent alot of things so it may look out of wack.

Comment: Stop mixing console and GUI. Choose one or the other. If you're using the console, stop using the dialog box and get input from the console. If you're going to get input from dialog boxes, stop using the console for output. One or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Input Dialogs to gather information from the User then why bother with the Scanner object? Your `keyboard.nextLine();` code line within the **for** loop is holding things up waiting for input and will do so for each iteration.